# How to show NA values as "NA" rather than " " in scan() function?

Tags: r, missing-data

I try to import a data set into R using the scan() function, however, the missing values which are actually blank in the tab delimited text file, appear as "" and not NA. Is there a way to show them as NA?
I tried the following but nothing changed:

```
data=scan(file="GBM.txt", sep='\t', what="", na.strings="NA")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `na.strings` argument defines the way missing values appear in the file rather than what you want them to be represented as in the R object.

I created a test file that looks like this:

```
1   2   3       4
```

Note: The values are separated by tabs, as in your code you specified "/t" as the separater.

Reading the file in with scan and `na.strings = ""`.

```
data <- scan(file = "GBM.txt", sep = '\t', what = "", na.strings = "")
```

That gives a data vector with the empty/ missing values being NAs:

```
data
>[1] "1" "2" "3" NA  "4"
```

Comment: I want them to appear as NA m. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, thats what using `na.strings = ""` does. I extended my answer to make it more explicit.